# Python unit testing specifics

Tags: python, testing

I have a fairly complex system that I want to test using python.  My test code will interact with the system using a Python module I've already written.  There are a few things however, that I haven't been able to figure out, regarding the testing framework.  I haven't selected one yet, but obviously I feel directed to [`unittest`](http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html).

1. Passing parameters to the tests. I need to pass a specific ID to many different parts of my test code, depending on which component of the system I am testing.  Does unittest provide for this? In other words, right now I just have a test script, which I run like this: `./testscript.py 123 win 32`  How can I pass the same parameters similarly in a testing framework?
2. `unittest` provides for `setUp()` and `tearDown()` methods, but they are called before/after *each* test method. How can I have functions that are called before/after the entire battery of tests in a `TestCase`?

Maybe `unittest` is not what I actually want to use?

Comment: for #1 see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1029891/python-unittest-is-there-a-way-to-pass-command-line-options-to-the-app it can be done

Comment: Thanks F.C. that makes logical sense. I'm assuming the only way to actually get parameters to the modules I'm testing with then are globals.

Comment: So shall I accept my own answer, or would you like to make that an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: you could add the solution from that answer to yours and accept it in case someone comes here looking for a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for #2, it seems that [`setUpClass()` and `tearDownClass()`](http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html#setupclass-and-teardownclass) are designed for this. The documentation even shows an example of using it to `createExpensiveConnectionObject()`.

Answer (score 1):

I use tox to run my tests across multiple configurations. Some of my unittests skip certain tests if an optional module isn't there, which means I needed a check to make sure that the module detection code works. Tox doesn't have an easy way to specify any command-line arguments, so the easiest solution was to go through an environment variable.

F.C.'s pointer to [python, unittest: is there a way to pass command line options to the app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1029891/python-unittest-is-there-a-way-to-pass-command-line-options-to-the-app) applies if you decide that extra arguments are the way to go.