# call different methods in unittest according to input arguments

Tags: python, unit-testing, testcase

I'm writing a test script in Python subclassing `unittest.TestCase`. There're multiple test methods starting with `test_`.

What I want to do know is to invoke different test methods according to input arguments, like `trial test.py -option`. I wonder if there's a way to do this in the unittest framework. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11380413/python-unittest-passing-arguments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can! [**Straight from the unittest documentation on organizing your test code**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#organizing-test-code)

---

**Assume you have a TestCase that looks like this guy:**

```
import unittest

class WidgetTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.widget = Widget('The widget')

    def tearDown(self):
        self.widget.dispose()
        self.widget = None

    def test_default_size(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.widget.size(), (50,50),
                     'incorrect default size')

    def test_resize(self):
        self.widget.resize(100,150)
        self.assertEqual(self.widget.size(), (100,150),
                     'wrong size after resize')
```

---

**Now you can do something like this in your TestSuite setup/run code:**

```
def suite():
    suite = unittest.TestSuite()
    suite.addTest(WidgetTestCase('test_default_size'))
    suite.addTest(WidgetTestCase('test_resize'))
    return suite
```

---

Obviously, you can use [argparse](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/argparse.html) to set your own options and customize the structure to your needs. Check out the documentation on the [Organizing Your Test Code](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#organizing-test-code) section. That example is just the most explicit one, there are plenty of other ways to test this cat.