# Unittest test framework, with parameter test cases how to pass parameters when calling

Tags: python-unittest

```py
import unittest, requests, json;

class Test_interface_py_cm(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        print("<<<<<< start test >>>>>>")
        self.base_url = "http://192.168.11.67:8063/api/"
        self.s = requests.Session()
        self.headers = {'content-type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'}

    def tearDown(self):
        print("<<<<<< end test >>>>>>")

    def test1(self, arg_page, arg_pagesize):
        data = {"minTimes": 9}
        r = self.s.post(
            self.base_url + "mining/analysis/community/stranger/list/page/" + arg_page + "/pagesize/" + arg_pagesize,
            data=json.dumps(data), headers=self.headers)
        result = r.json()
        self.assertEqual(r.status_code, 200)
        self.assertEqual(result["errCode"], 0)
        self.assertEqual(result['data']['name'], '31598')
        r.connection.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

When I want to pass parameters to the `test1` method, in the `main()` method, how to pass parameters to `test1`（Must use `unittest` test framework to call）

Comment: Perhaps this can help https://stackoverflow.com/a/20702984/2091925

Comment: @WillKeeling Thank you for your answer But still did not solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

If you want to parameterize your test with the `arg_page` and `arg_pagesize` arguments, you could build the test methods dynamically like this.

```py
class Test_interface_py_cm(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        print("<<<<<< start test >>>>>>")
        self.base_url = "http://192.168.11.67:8063/api/"
        self.s = requests.Session()
        self.headers = {'content-type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'}

    def tearDown(self):
        print("<<<<<< end test >>>>>>")


if __name__ == '__main__':

    def create_test(name, arg_page, arg_pagesize):
        def test1(self):
            data = {"minTimes": 9}
            r = self.s.post(
                self.base_url + "mining/analysis/community/stranger/list/page/" + arg_page + "/pagesize/" + arg_pagesize,
                data=json.dumps(data), headers=self.headers)
            result = r.json()
            self.assertEqual(r.status_code, 200)
            self.assertEqual(result["errCode"], 0)
            self.assertEqual(result['data']['name'], '31598')
            r.connection.close()
        setattr(Test_interface_py_cm, name, test1)

    create_test(name='test1', arg_page='page1', arg_pagesize=10)
    create_test(name='test2', arg_page='page1', arg_pagesize=20)
    create_test(name='test3', arg_page='page2', arg_pagesize=10)
    create_test(name='test4', arg_page='page2', arg_pagesize=20)

    unittest.main()
```

In the example above, the test methods are dynamically added to the test class by calling `create_test`. Each method runs with a different value of `arg_page` and `arg_pagesize`. The name you supply must of course be unique.

Comment: This method can indeed pass arguments to the ```test case```, but if I have a lot of ```test cases``` and the ```test case``` arguments are all different, then do I have to encapsulate a method when passing each ```test case```? This seems to be more troublesome

Comment: Yes if you're looking to parameterize multiple test methods, then you'd need to encapsulate each in a closure like in the above example. A bit cumbersome, but given that `unittest` doesn't support passing parameters to tests, the options are rather limited.

Comment: Maybe try ```@parameterized.expand``` to pass parameters