# how to change key form dictionary from cmd unittest

Tags: robotframework, python-unittest

I have question about **Robotframework** and **Unittest (python)**: In Robotframework, there is possiblity to change variable in command line, for example: 
`pybot -d Results -v ENVIRONMENT:stage Test01.robot` . 
Do you know any possibility to change it in unittest (**python test framework**) due command line?

Comment: Pardon my French, but what does this question has to do with RobotFramework - apart from using it as an example of a system that accept variable setting through its CLI arguments? It's a straightforward `unittest` question.

Comment: To your question - your unittest  module most probably has `if __name__ == "__main__":` section - handle any CLI arguments passed in it, and change the tests' variables. Mind this is highly unorthodox. Here's [a question and answers how, and why not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11380413/python-unittest-passing-arguments)

Comment: Ok - I am not proffesional in unittest, but I've worked in Robot Framework and I'm interested in approach to CI in unitest:

Comment: Sorry: there is all of my comment: Ok - I am not proffesional in unittest, but I've worked in Robot Framework and I'm interested in approach to CI in unitest: I have my tests in Robot Framework and they are integretad to GitLab and pipeline. .yml contains command: pybot -d Results -v ENVIRONMENT:stage when chcanges are merged into stage env, and `pybot -d Results -v ENVIRONMENT:prod` after deploy to production is buit.  So there is my question, maybe I was not clear enough: How You do it in unittest? I have my dictionary with env: `environments = {"Prod": "ccc.com", "stage_1": "https://ff.com"