# Python unit testing with unittest module

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, automated-tests, python-unittest

This is how I wrote the code to start a test with the **unittest** module but it is returning as 0 tests. Is the return making any problems? (I am able to share the complete code but it is long). Posting the code and the script below:

1. Script:

   ```
   class Test1(unittest.TestCase):

       def get_avg(temps, predict_month):
          #print("Temp:==>>>",temps,"predict_month:=>>>>",predict_month)
           temp_arr = []
           idx_num = month_dict[predict_month]
           temp_arr.append(float(temps[idx_num]))
           for i in range (0, 5, 1):
               idx_num += 1
               idx_num = idx_num % 12
               temp_arr.append(float(temps[idx_num]))
               pass
           # return np.average(temp_arr, axis=0)
   ```
2. Showing the error with 0 tests:

   ```
   Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

   OK
   ```
3. I ran the main **unittest** at the end with this:

   ```
   if __name__ == '__main__':
        unittest.main()
   ```

I want to know about my faults and loopholes.

Answer (score 0):

The test function should start with `test`:

```
class Test1(unittest.TestCase):
 ...
 def test_get_avg(temps, predict_month):
    #print("Temp:==>>>",temps,"predict_month:=>>>>",predict_month)
     temp_arr = []
     idx_num = month_dict[predict_month]
     temp_arr.append(float(temps[idx_num]))
     for i in range (0, 5, 1):
         idx_num += 1
         idx_num = idx_num % 12
         temp_arr.append(float(temps[idx_num]))
         pass
     # return np.average(temp_arr, axis=0) 
 ...
if __name__ == '__main__':
     unittest.main()
```

Feel free to check the [documentation regarding `unittest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#basic-example)

Comment: Thank you. Implemented it. The same error is coming.

Comment: Ey, I just realized that you are passing some parameters to `test_get_avg` function. You should create a different function to assign the values as class atribute, and pass only "self". Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11380413/python-unittest-passing-arguments). So putting "test_" at the begining of the function name + passing the right parameters, it should work

Comment: puting some random values, check the updated code and let me know if it helped

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a function that does something and you want to test it. In this case, you need to take this function out of the class, and in the class with tests write the tests themselves, and not the function that you are testing. Test method cannot accept arguments like temps and predict_month.
Your function returns something, and in the test we can pass certain values ​​​​into it and check that it returned the expected result:

```
import unittest


def get_avg(temps, predict_month):
    #print("Temp:==>>>",temps,"predict_month:=>>>>",predict_month)
    temp_arr = []
    idx_num = month_dict[predict_month]
    temp_arr.append(float(temps[idx_num]))
    for i in range (0, 5, 1):
        idx_num += 1
        idx_num = idx_num % 12
        temp_arr.append(float(temps[idx_num]))
        pass
    # return np.average(temp_arr, axis=0) 

class Test1(unittest.TestCase):
    
    def test_get_avg(self):
        # your test code
        self.assertEqual(get_avg(temps test value, predict_month test value), expected_result)
```