# Python: run a unittest.TestCase without calling unittest.main()?

Tags: python, python-2.7, unit-testing, command-line-arguments, python-unittest

I've written a small test suite in Python's unittest:

```
class TestRepos(unittest.TestCase):

@classmethod
def setUpClass(cls):
    """Get repo lists from the svn server."""
    ...

def test_repo_list_not_empty(self):
    """Assert the the repo list is not empty"""
    self.assertTrue(len(TestRepoLists.all_repos)>0)

def test_include_list_not_empty(self):
    """Assert the the include list is not empty"""
    self.assertTrue(len(TestRepoLists.svn_dirs)>0)

...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main(testRunner=xmlrunner.XMLTestRunner(output='tests', 
                                                 descriptions=True))
```

The output is formatted as Junit test using [the xmlrunner pacakge](https://github.com/danielfm/unittest-xml-reporting).

I've added a command line argument for toggling JUnit output:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Validate repo lists.')
    parser.add_argument('--junit', action='store_true')
    args=parser.parse_args()
    print args
    if (args.junit):
        unittest.main(testRunner=xmlrunner.XMLTestRunner(output='tests', 
                                                     descriptions=True))
    else:
        unittest.main(TestRepoLists)
```

The problem is that running the script without `--junit` works, but calling it with `--junit` clashes with `unittest`'s arguments:

```
option --junit not recognized
Usage: test_lists_of_repos_to_branch.py [options] [test] [...]

Options:
  -h, --help       Show this message
  -v, --verbose    Verbose output
  ...
```

**How can I run a unittest.TestCase without calling unittest.main()?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You really should use a proper test runner (such as `nose` or `zope.testing`). In your specific case, I'd use [`argparser.parse_known_args()`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.parse_known_args) instead:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False)
    parser.add_argument('--junit', action='store_true')
    options, args = parser.parse_known_args()

    testrunner = None
    if (options.junit):
        testrunner = xmlrunner.XMLTestRunner(output='tests', descriptions=True)
    unittest.main(testRunner=testrunner, argv=sys.argv[:1] + args)
```

Note that I removed `--help` from your argument parser, so the `--junit` option becomes hidden, but it will no longer interfere with `unittest.main`. I also pass the remaining arguments on to `unittest.main()`.

Comment: `File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/unittest/main.py", line 93, in __init__
    self.progName = os.path.basename(argv[0])
IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: Thanks for the fix. It works with `--junit`, but without it I get `Ran 0 tests in 0.000s`.

Comment: @AdamMatan: Remove the `TestRepoLists` argument?

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I guess I should really look into `nose` for future tests.

Comment: Here is another variation of this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8660290/366698