# Unittest not Running

Tags: python, testing, command-line-arguments

I am running a unittest using arguments from command line. Below is my test code.

```
import unittest
import sys
from toolbox.models import *
akit_id = sys.argv[1]

class TestQuizCase(unittest.TestCase):

    def testupdate_quiz(self):
        akit = AssignmentKit.objects.get(pk = akit_id)
        akit.update_score_grade()
        self.assertEqual(akit.marks, 50000)

if __name__ == "__main___":
    del sys.argv[1:]
    unittest.main()
```

Now from command line I'm doing:

```
>>> python test_quiz.py 2000
```

Nothing comes, thus no tests ran. I tried logging and found that the control is not even entering the test function. What am I missing is it sys.argv which is causing problem?

Comment: Why are you deleting `sys.argv`?

Comment: I read on SO that I need to delete them. Without them it wasn't working. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1029891/python-unittest-is-there-a-way-to-pass-command-line-options-to-the-app

Comment: @alecxe: `unittest.main()` reads `sys.argv` and the `2000` argument would interfere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have **three** undrescores in `"__main___"`. So the code never enters `unittest.main()`. There should be only two.